# How to change caf High quality(sample rate) to caf Low quality(sample rate)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using `AVAudioRecorder`. I record the audio in `caf format` with 44100 sample rate. It recorded successfully. After recording I want to convert already recorded `caf` audio file with 11025 and 22050 sample rate. Is it possible to change high to low & medium sample rate.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 6, AVAudioSession can take that input and can likely convert it via this method:

[`setPreferredSampleRate: error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setPreferredSampleRate%3aerror%3a).